# Database issues with deploying ASP.NET MVC web app in Azure

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure

I have a web app published to Azure built in Visual Studio MVC. Many times after publishing updated files the app will fail when querying the database so it seems. For instance the home page will load fine but the app will crash when a link is selected that connects to my database. It is a MySQL database hosted remotely.

Here's the error for the deployed version:
[image: Error]

I'm not sure how to interpret the error either and I've looked into enabling development mode in my app but as far as I can tell it is enabled.

Occasionally after a few restarts through Azure the app will start working fine and the app consistently works when I build and launch through Visual Studio. It leads me to believe this is an Azure issue conflicting with my data base setup.

It's making testing a real hassle and I don't have confidence the app/database will be up when I need it to.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to get the detailed error message to interpret the error.

To get the error message in azure, we can watch the diagnostic logs, about how to do this, we can refer to: [Enable diagnostics logging for web apps in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log)

We can also display the error message directly on browser. For example, if you are using ASP.NET core MVC, we can do as below:

Replace the below code of Startup class:

```
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }
```

With:

```
        app.UseBrowserLink();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
```

When the error occurs again, we can see the error message at browser directly